# how to store and retrieve a 8 bit binary value into a bin file using java

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Jesper {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("example.bin")) {
        out.write(10100001);
        out.write(10000001);
    }
}
}
```

i am storing 8 bit= 1 byte values- 10100001 and 10000001 in to the bin file example.bin.
on executing this 21,81 are stored in the bin file. which is wrong. how to store these exact values and retrieve them?

Comment: Store it as string or store it as it is and retrieve it as number and convert that number to binary string..

Comment: will this work---out.write(Integer.parseInt(byte4));

Comment: byte4=10000001 here and its a string value.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're storing the integers "ten million, one hundred thousand and one" `10,100,001` and "ten million and one" `10,000,001`. If you want these numbers to be binary, you need to tell Java: `0b10100001` and `0b10000001`. But Java will still think they're integers, you need to tell it that they're bytes.

But `out.write()` expects a String object. While it is happy to convert a `char` into a string, if it sees a `byte` it wil convert it into a number.

```
out.write((char)0b10100001);
out.write((char)0b10000001);
```

---

For example:

```
String s;
for (char c=0b00000000;c<0b100000000;++c) {
    s = s + c;
} // for
out.write(s);
```

Check the above code: does it write 128 bytes to your binary file?

Comment: so i should just add ((byte)0b10000001); this right ?

Comment: i wrote exactly-- out.write((byte)0b10100001);  but it shows A1 in the bin file

Comment: `A1` is hexadecimal for binary `10100001`.  That's what you _should_ see.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I forgot `write()` converted to `String`. See my edit.

Comment: but if i store it in a string__out.write(Integer.parseInt(byte1)); where byte1= 10000011  then its showing 8A in bin file where as it should be 83

Comment: Don't write it as an integer: don't write it as a byte. Write it as a char, like in my code above.

Comment: i understand sir, but if i have the binary value in an int variable or a string variable then how will i write it into the bin file

Comment: @ASHWIN I've added an example for writing a `String`. It depends on how you get the binary bytes into the string. Writing an `int` is harder...

Comment: now i understand, it depends on how we give the binary value to the string variable.